# Since Higgs boson the only non-rotating elementary particle, does it keep its orientation?

Tags: quantum-spin, higgs

Higgs boson seems to be the only non-rotating elementary particle (unsure about Planck particle). Does it mean that by studiing Higgs bosons one can find the anisotropy in the physical space (or find a distinguished dimension)?

Comment: You don't need to use a fundamental scalar particle for that, e.g. the so-called singlet state of two entangled spin half particles 1/sqrt(2) [|up>|down> - |down>|up>] is also invariant under rotations.

Comment: The usual $\pi$ and $K$ mesons have no spin.

Comment: I think composite particles like alpha particle, for instance, also have zero spin. If this could reveal anything, they may be easier to work with.